# Calculating Grobner Bases

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis

In this question, $ℚ[x,y,z]$ is endowed with the *lexicographic order* with $x > y > z$.
Set $u:= x^2 + 2yz^2$ and $v:= y^2 - 3xz$. Denote by $J$ the ideal of $ℚ[x,y,z]$ generated by $u$ and $v$.

1. Compute a reduced Gröbner basis of $J$ by using Buchberger's algorithm.
2. Does $f:= x^2 - xz + 4$ belong to $J$?
3. Prove that $V(J)$ is infinite.
4. Does $g:= (x + y + z)^{2014}$ belong to $J$?

Answer (score 3):

$\mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]$ is endowed with lex: $x > y > z$.

$J = \langle x^2 + 2yz^2, xz - \frac{1}{3}y^2 \rangle = \langle u, v \rangle$.

1) The Buchberger's algorithm would go as follows:

$$S(u,v) = x^2 z + 2yz^3 - x^2 z + \frac{1}{3}xy^2 = \frac{1}{3}xy^2 + 2yz^3 = \frac{1}{3} p$$

Since $p$ cannot be reduced any further with respect to $u$ and $v$ then $G_J = \{ x^2 + 2yz^2, xz - \frac{1}{3}y^2 \} \cup \{ xy^2 + 6yz^3 \}$ and $J = \langle u,v,p \rangle$.

$$S(v,p) = xy^2 z - \frac{1}{3}y^4 - xy^2 z - 6yz^4 = -\frac{1}{3}y^4 - 6yz^4 = -\frac{1}{3}q$$

Again since $q$ cannot be reduced any further with respect to $u,v$ and $p$ then $G_J = \{ x^2 + 2yz^2, xz - \frac{1}{3}y^2, xy^2 + 6yz^3 \} \cup \{ y^4 + 18yz^4 \}$ and $J = \langle u,v,p,q \rangle$.

It is easy to check that any other $S$-polynomial reduces to $0$ modulo $J$. So $G_J$ is a Groebner basis of $J$. It is also straightforward to verify that $G_J$ is a reduced Groebner basis of $J$.

2) No, it doesn't. It reduces to $-\frac{1}{3}y^2-2yz^2+4$ with respect to $G_J$.

3) Elimination ideal $J_z = J \cap k[z] = \{ 0 \}$ which means that $\mathbb{V}(J_z) = \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{V}(J)$ is a curve in $\mathbb{Q}^3$.

4) $g \in J \subseteq \sqrt{J} \iff g_{red} \in \sqrt{J}$, where $g_{red} = x + y + z$.

To check radical membership you can use Proposition 8 (Chapter 4, paragraph 2) of "Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms" by Cox, Little, O'Shea. It says that:

$$g_{red} \in \sqrt{J} \iff 1 \in \langle u, v, 1 - w g_{red} \rangle = \hat{J} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}[x,y,z,w].$$

Computing reduced Groebner basis of $\hat{J}$ with respect ot grlex ($x>y>z>w$) you'll get 5 nonconstant polynomials, which means $1 \notin \hat{J}$ and $g \notin J$. (I do not recommend you to compute Groebner basis of $\hat{J}$ with respect to lex ordering in this case, because it has enormous polynomials).

In fact, in this particular case you have $J = \sqrt{J}$, so it is easier to reduce $g_{red} = x + y + z$ with respect to $G_J$. However, it is not easy to show that $J = \sqrt{J}$.

Comment: great! is there any intuition in solving this problem or you used computer? for example knowing $J = \sqrt{J}$?

Comment: Questions 1-4 are pretty easy and you can find answers to those in any standard literature on Groebner bases. Checking whether $J = \sqrt{J}$ is quite hard though. So yes, I used computer algebra system. But here is some information. Note that $J$ is not prime. In particular, $J = \langle x,y \rangle \cap \langle y^3+18z^4, 3xz-y^2, xy+6z^3, x^2+2yz^2 \rangle$. So to prove that $J$ is radical you may need to prove that components of its primary decomposition are prime. While it is obvious that the first component is prime, it is less easy to show that the second one is prime as well.

Comment: Mathew: this is a good answer.If you have not question about this answer mark accept to exclude the question from unaccepted list.